# The average of a text file with 10000 numbers in python

Tags: python, text-files, average, mean

I'm trying to solve this problem that reads one file and computes and presents the average (mean). using the functions def mean(lst) that computes the mean for a given list of integers lst.

```
def mean (lst):

    filename = "file_10k_integers_A.txt"
    with open(filename) as f:
        lst = [int(line) for line in f]

print("The average value is ", sum(lst)/len(lst))

lst = dir
print(mean(dir))
```

but every time I try to print it I always get the error "invalid literal for int() with base 10:" and I'm thinking I'm getting it because of text file with 10000 numbers.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

here's some numbers of how the text file looks like

```
384, 78, 894, 464, 681, 256, 729, 659, 393, 496
800, 329, 301, 979, 792, 537, 913, 279, 847, 276
33, 453, 892, 54, 921, 863, 400, 644, 923, 565
195, 656, 830, 701, 889, 923, 759, 635, 732, 395
761, 843, 417, 874, 954, 235, 31, 355, 980, 782
155, 437, 99, 273, 566, 366, 279, 683, 85, 351
306, 713, 776, 956, 38, 292, 536, 152, 55, 72
732, 83, 570, 113, 157, 605, 638, 633, 453, 480
863, 514, 864, 423, 866, 156, 665, 193, 508, 43
878, 813, 91, 235, 353, 593, 226, 52, 938, 803
724, 611, 599, 155, 797, 150, 31, 971, 776, 711
482, 921, 709, 296, 822, 599, 54, 134, 768, 82
335, 694, 124, 976, 6, 189, 554, 788, 106, 975
206, 165, 667, 44, 334, 272, 988, 487, 464, 995
489, 62, 21, 151, 261, 263, 362, 738, 262, 582
619, 859, 938, 141, 827, 507, 822, 112, 686, 152
479, 291, 236, 237, 448, 36, 945, 529, 919, 12
766, 923, 634, 754, 326, 670, 862, 272, 664, 921
890, 256, 311, 450, 111, 109, 977, 52, 990, 789
205, 690, 525, 323, 979, 111, 310, 567, 808, 622
138, 257, 419, 695, 632, 568, 176, 72, 706, 96
790, 359, 951, 665, 421, 731, 910, 620, 347, 757
754, 759, 103, 9, 80, 956, 732, 491, 775, 344
688, 381, 205, 107, 310, 534, 189, 110, 435, 700
437, 225, 124, 998, 801, 295, 446, 959, 257, 150
645, 110, 937, 372, 588, 489, 318, 907, 490, 748
645, 877, 53, 213, 615, 85, 555, 107, 194, 824
120, 433, 714, 455, 190, 753, 326, 395, 3, 861
```

Comment: You should split every line on comma (`,`)...

Answer (score 2):

Your code tries to convert whole line which includes many numbers to single integer. You should split each line by `,` and then convert result to integers.
For example:

```py
with open(filename) as f:
    lst = []
    for line in f:
        for i in line.split(','):
            lst.append(int(i))
```

Comment: @Jab yes, but `int` does not care about spaces (`int('   123   ')` returns `123`).